# Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2 on .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to use ASP.NET Web API 2 with .net 4.0? I tried to upgrade from an older version but I get:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To answer my own question:

No, it is NOT possible to use Web API 2 with .net 4.0:

[image]

This is taken from a slide by [Damian Edwards](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DEV-B314#fbid=tr6EinQd0mz). You can find additinal info [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1937143.aspx?Is%20ASP%20NET%20MVC%205%20and%20Web%20API%202%200%20supported%20on%20NET%204%200%20and%20IIS6%20).

Comment: If you check @MikeL below, that's a valid workaround.

Comment: This only works on the client side. On the server you need .net 4.5!

Answer (score 22):

FWIW, I had a .NET 4.0 requirement on the client (die WinXP!), but I could do .NET 4.5 on the server.  So, I have WebApi2 running server side, but the WebApi1 client package running on the client, handling serialization, etc.

Using the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio and choosing my client project in the default project dropdown, I was able to:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 4.0.30506.0
```

Everything thereafter worked well.

Comment: nice! web API 1 is fine for alot of client calls