# Simple example with REST WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf-data-services

I need to develop data transfer between two sites and believe that with our .Net environment a RESTful implementation would be much better than one with `FTP` (ugh). However, simple examples are hard to find, and the REST basics obscured by ADO.NET or lots of clever details, so I am trying to make one really simple myself. Still, I need some help on principles and implementation to get it to work.

In a VisualStudio web project I created a new item `WCF Data Service` and a class for the data. This is App_Code\WidgetRecord.cs:

```
//using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;//List
using System.Linq;//Where
//using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;//ServiceContract, OperationContract
using System.Runtime.Serialization;//DataContract
using System.Diagnostics;//Debug.WriteLine()

/// <summary>
/// Declare operations for a service
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract]
public interface IScandataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<WidgetRecord> List();

    [OperationContract]
    WidgetRecord Get(string Id);

    [OperationContract]
    int Put(string Id, string Desc);
}//end interface

/// <summary>
/// Fake database storage for testing the WCF Data Service
/// </summary>
public static class Database
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fake database table
    /// </summary>
    public static List<WidgetRecord> WidgetTable = new List<WidgetRecord>() { 
    new WidgetRecord("0001", "red"), 
    new WidgetRecord("0002", "blue") };
}

/// <summary>
/// Implement operations for a service.
/// Representation of a table of widgets identified by scanned barcodes
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class WidgetRecord : IScandataService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Row column: the id which could be a scanned barcode
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Row column: widget description.
    /// (Other columns could be a timestamp, location etc)
    /// </summary>
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dummy initializer, needed for ....(??)
    /// </summary>
    public WidgetRecord()
    {
    return;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializer to populate the fake database storage.
    /// Creates a new widget record.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Id"></param>
    public WidgetRecord(string Id, string Desc)
    {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.Desc = Desc;
    return;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// List all stored widgets
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    public List<WidgetRecord> List()
    {
    return Database.WidgetTable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get info on an existing widget
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    public WidgetRecord Get(string Id)
    {
    WidgetRecord sd = Database.WidgetTable.Where(n => n.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (sd == null)
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Found: {0} - {1}", sd.Id, sd.Desc));
    else
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Not found: id={0}", Id));
    return sd;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new widget to the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Id"></param>
    /// <param name="Desc"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    public int Put(string Id, string Desc)
    {
    Database.WidgetTable.Add(new WidgetRecord(Id, Desc));
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Put: {0} - {1}", Id, Desc));
    return 0;
    }
}//end class
```

In other sources I often see a `partial class` for the `[DataContract]` with field members, and another class with the methods. I don't understand why this should be separated. I am just trying to use the ServiceContract interface as a base class for my data class. Anyway, my class with fields and methods builds OK.

I refer to the above class in the `code-behind` of `WcfDataService.svc`, which is `App_Code\WcfDataService.cs`:

```
//using System;
using System.Data.Services;//IDataServiceConfiguration, EntitySetRights, ServiceOperationRights, DataServiceProtocolVersion
//using System.Data.Services.Common;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.ServiceModel.Web;

public class WcfDataService : DataService<WidgetRecord>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(IDataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
    // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
    // Examples:
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
    //config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    return;
    }
}//end class
```

This all builds and runs, but basically does nothing, yet.

```
http://localhost:56794/website_for_rest/wcfDataService.svc/
-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" 
    xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xml:base="http://localhost:56794/website_for_rest/WcfDataService.svc/">
    <workspace>
        <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
    </workspace>
</service>
```

I cannot add a command to the URL:

```
http://localhost:56794/website_for_rest/wcfDataService.svc/List
-->
page not found
```

Do I need to add something to the `web.config`? VS gave me a 126-line `web.config` and I don't know where to add what.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you just need a simple REST service, why not use [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)? It's simpler and seems to be receiving better support from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, I like simple, and just started reading on Web Api.

Comment: Web API seems to require VS2013 and .Net4.5? We are here still on VS2010 and .Net3.5. It is not that simple to use simple tools :-) I am still hoping that somebody can help me with my current example. It should be close to working.

Comment: I've used it with VS2010, but it [requires at least .NET 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953263/microsoft-asp-net-web-api-2-on-net-4-0). Sorry, I can't help you with WCF as I'm not familiar enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, at least for me, that the simplest REST example does not use WCF Data Service, which is a framework to simplify REST. However, there is only a need to simplify REST if you have a lot of data and many actions to implement. For a starter, and for simple data transfers, you can do REST without a framework. And when you need a framework, there is a lot of choice, see e.g. [this list of a few dozen frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_frameworks). To begin with, SOAP is one of the older ones, and fallen out of favor because of being too complex. Same with Web Services. Apparently, WCF Data Service, meant to succeed WS, is in turn replaced by Web API.

The problem with such frameworks is that they might create new problems. For me it is a disadvantage that I have to upgrade my tooling, because VS2010 with .Net3.5 does not support Web API. Upgrading is a Good Thing, but not if it interferes with a large project I am working on. Or WCF Data Services is just not clear to me, has all kinds of smart bindings that I do not grasp, see my question. Many examples exist for WCF DS, but are combined with ADO.NET to help you handling lots of tables.

Staying with the Microsoft environment (VS, .Net, Asp), it is easy to start with plain REST. Just create an empty web page, say `Default.aspx`, and start programming REST functionality in its `Page_Load()`.

To see if a GET, PUT, POST etc request has arrived, look at `Request.RequestType`.

To get at the data in the HTTP body: `Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength)`.

If you need to handle authorization, get the username and password from the Authentication Http header line with: `Request.Params["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]`, which is base64 encoded. Then you will want a secure connection with HTTPS, which encrypts the entire HTTP packet, including HTTP headers, at the transport (TCP) level.

To return HTTP status codes and/or error messages, just add a regular asp text control to the page. It is also possible to replace the entire http response with fiddling with the `Response` object, if you want to RESTful return a data structure.

With the Telerik `fiddler` tool, it is easy to craft an HTTP packet to test your simple REST server page.

For clients to reach your page with better URLs you need to use some URL rewriting. This involves downloading and installing a rewrite module, and adding rules to your web.config. [This seems to be a good source with detailed explanations and examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Of course using a nice framework would be great, but a barebones implementation is a great way to study REST, and is already a great improvement over older FTP methods of exchanging data as still seen very often in my industry.

Thanks to Mason, who helped me realize that WCF DS is just one of many frameworks.

Comment: A couple of misconceptions, IMO, in your answer: " Apparently, WCF Data Service, meant to succeed WS, is in turn replaced by Web API."  WCF (and WCF Data Services) replaced the legacy ASMX web services (and .NET Remoting), specific Microsoft technologies, not web services in general.

Comment: 2. "SOAP is one of the older ones, and fallen out of favor because of being too complex." Also not true.  SOAP is still very much alive and still used, even for new development.  RESTful services are an alternative and used (in my experience, at least) extensively (but not exclusively) with mobile platforms, but SOAP is not dead.  SOAP and REST are two flavors of web services.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your clarifications. My statements are based on what I have read about REST, and those people at the bleeding edge of technology of course consider SOAP and the Microsoft WS as obsolete. Not dead: true. Like FTP and COBOL, that I would like to declare obsolete and/or legacy, but surely still widely in use. But this all distracts from my main point, which is that REST can be implemented with or without a framework, which was not clear to me when I started studying REST last week.

Comment: You're welcome.  I will agree that REST is the preferred method in many situations, but SOAP is not obsolete, and neither is WCF.  WCF does have it uses (for example, it has more transport options than REST, which is only over HTTP).  SOAP can be implemented without a framework as well, though it would be a bit more challenging.  In any event, if REST suits your needs then by all means use it.  I'd just caution you to not write SOAP or WCF off as obsolete, because they're not, IMO.  Happy coding :)

Comment: @Tim Point taken. While my barebones REST implementation is my ticket out of the legacy FTP data transfer method in our company app, I might get to more intelligent REST/WCF/SOAP solutions at some future point.